# Dictionary update method in Python 3.4

Tags: python, dictionary

The `update(...)` method for dictionary ([see doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)) has an **optional** argument `other`.

I understand well what it does when the argument is another dictionary. But if I don't put any argument, it simply does nothing.

```
>>> a = {'1':'first', '2':'second'}
>>> a
{'2': 'second', '1': 'first'}
>>> a.update()
>>> a
{'2': 'second', '1': 'first'}
```

**What I don't understand is why is this an optional argument, and not a compulsory one.**

There is no point in doing `a.update()` with no arguments, or am I wrong somewhere? I thought it could maybe be a trick for passing an iterable of key/value pairs instead of another dictionary as an argument.

Comment: [The `dict.update()` method now accepts the same argument forms as the `dict` constructor. This includes any mapping, any iterable of key/value pairs, and keyword arguments. (Contributed by Raymond Hettinger.)](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.4.html#other-language-changes)

Comment: I guess that the method takes `**kwargs` as parameter. So it is natural that the argument is optional

Comment: Reason why they unified `dict.update` and `dict.__init__`: [`dict.update` should take a 2-tuple sequence like `dict.__init__`](http://bugs.python.org/issue904720)